# Linq Cannot implicitity Convert DateTime,Double

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I get the following:

Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.DateTime?,double?>` to `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.DateTime,double>`

When I try to use a stored procedure within Entity Framework

Here is the code that I have:

```
    private Dictionary<DateTime, double> GetData(string columnName)
    {
        return db.SysReading(columnName, Convert.ToString(LocId)).
            ToDictionary( a => a.DateCollected, a => a.ElementReading);

    }
```

I am using a call to a Stored Procedure called SysReading. When I convert it to a dictionary, the return type is nullable which I do not want.

Comment: Consider making those properties non-nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it sounds like `a.DateCollected` is a `DateTime?` property instead of `DateTime`. If you believe *all* keys will have values, you can just use:

```
private Dictionary<DateTime, double> GetData(string columnName)
{
    return db.SysReading(columnName, Convert.ToString(LocId))
             .ToDictionary(a => a.DateCollected.Value, a => a.ElementReading);
}
```

Or you could filter and *then* convert:

```
private Dictionary<DateTime, double> GetData(string columnName)
{
    return db.SysReading(columnName, Convert.ToString(LocId))
             .Where(a => a.DateCollected.HasValue)
             .ToDictionary(a => a.DateCollected.Value, a => a.ElementReading);
}
```

Alternatively, change your method to return a `Dictionary<DateTime?, double>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly return non-nullable types:

```
    return db.SysReading(columnName, Convert.ToString(LocId)).
        ToDictionary( a => a.DateCollected.Value, a => a.ElementReading.Value);
```

This will throw an exception if any of those values are null.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing `Nullable` values. (so `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime`.

```
return db.SysReading(columnName, Convert.ToString(LocId)).
    ToDictionary( a => a.DateCollected.Value, a => a.ElementReading.Value);
```

But, if those values aren't meant to be `NULL`, the best thing to do (instead of  assuming those values will always have a value, and then call `.Value`) should be to modify your DB in order to make those columns non nullable (`NOT NULL`).

So then, calling your method would return a `Dictionary<System.DateTime,double>` object.

```
return db.SysReading(columnName, Convert.ToString(LocId)).
    ToDictionary( a => a.DateCollected, a => a.ElementReading);
```